# Implementing Ekathuwa Module in AngularJS transferring ng-repeat values to the modal

Tags: angularjs

I’m currently got stucked in implementing modal on angularjs. I’m still new with this framework and I’m using one of the modules that I got from ng-modules.org, https://github.com/sarath2/ngEkathuwa ngEkathuwa, which implements bootstrap 3 modal. However, I have difficulty in understanding how to transfer the values for the ng-repeat list to the modal using the module.

```
            <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="uti in $data">
                    <td data-title="'UTI Meter'" sortable="meter">
                        {{uti.item}}
                    </td>                   
                    <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="cdate" align="middle">
                        {{uti.cdate}}
                    </td>
                    <td align="middle" data-title="'Action'">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDelete" ng-click="deleteUti(uti.ikey)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Delete
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEdit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                        </button>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The examples from the github, http://plnkr.co/ebDtSMw6w0IZquaglEMe, only showed static data triggering from a button. I already combed the site and some says that you have to use resolve for the data to be transferred and subsequently, showed on your modal. Yet again, I can’t locate it on the documentation. I’m just wondering if that module only supports static data or the resolve should be done under the modal controller.

Anyways, below are the scripts and any help to get over this stumbling block will surely be very much appreciated.

Here is the controller: With resolve{} implemented.

```
myApp.controller('utiCtrl', 
    function gaugeCtrl($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $log, $http, $ekathuwa){

    $scope.addUTI = function(){
        $ekathuwa.modal({
            id: "modalUTI",
            scope: $scope,
            templateURL: "./tpl/modal-uti.html"
        });
    }

    $scope.deleteUti = function(ikey){
        var p = $ekathuwa.modal({
            id: "modalUtiDelete",
            scope: $scope,
            contentPreSize: "sm",
            controller: modalDeleteCtrl,
            templateURL: "./tpl/modal-delete.html",
            show: true,
            resolve: {
                meter: function(){
                    return 'Test';
                }
            }

        });

        $q.when(p).then(function (m) {
            m.modal('show');
        });
    }

    var modalDeleteCtrl = function ($scope, $p, meter) {

      $scope.meter = meter;
    };
});
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking here. Based on the docs, it doesn't look like ngEkathuwa uses a `resolve` option. Inside your modal's template, it has access to the scope that you pass in--so you can call methods and set data on your scope just as you can with any other template.

Comment: How do i get the value that i pass from ng-click="deleteUti(uti.ikey)" and pass it over to the modal and eventually display it through the modal template?

Comment: Your modal has access to your scope, so you'd attach it to your scope--just like any other Angular view. See here for an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PMSAhaTuawF7lirOXAwd?p=preview

Comment: What you did was data coming from the modal and transferred to the parent screen. It is good and i'll keep it in mind for future use. However, what i wan't to do is the other way around, to pass the data from the parent screen coming from the ng-repeat iteration and display that data from the parent screen to the modal.

Comment: Scopes in Angular are two-way. Simply set some data or call a method. I've updated the Plunker example with a couple buttons that write back to the scope from the modal.

Comment: I figured it out. I just need to declare it by using $scope to get the passed value thru the function. Your example helped me understand the concept fully. Thank you for taking the time to help me with coming up with a solution. I'll be posting the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer to my question. Thank you Brandon Tilley for your example it gave me further understanding on the subject.

I need to declare the passed value ikey inside the modal by scope. Unlike the modal using ui.bootstrap, this module uses two-way binding as well and does not use resolve{} to display the data to the modal interface.

```
    $scope.deleteUti = function(ikey){
        $scope.meter = ikey;
        $ekathuwa.modal({
            id: "modalUtiDelete",
            scope: $scope,
            contentPreSize: "sm",
            controller: modalDeleteCtrl,
            templateURL: "./tpl/modal-delete.html"

        });

        var modalDeleteCtrl = function ($scope) {

        };
    }
```